# Can no longer ask questions

Tags: support, post-ban

So I am no longer allowed to ask questions, presumably because of my first two. However, I have been actively participating in the community since then, and have acquired 741 reputation. I am confused as to why 741 reputation is not enough to balance two legitimate but poorly presented questions. Can someone inform me what I should do to be able to ask questions again?

Comment: I do not see any ban. What does it say if you click on ASK QUESTION?

Comment: What? Why couldn't you ask a question? As far as I know, and as long as your account is not suspended, you can always ask questions within the current limits [per day/per month limits](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/38053).

Comment: @julien Not so. MSE has [automatic question ban](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10717/) enabled. This is not shown in the user's profile to anyone except maybe mods.

Comment: @PostNoBills Ok. Thanks for the information.

Comment: It seems clear yours is a situation only a moderator can deal with, so there's no point posting it here --- bring it to the attention of the moderators, instead.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Moderators cannot lift question bans.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker But hopefully the moderators can see who gets banned and decide whether the trigger is too light. When question ban was introduced Shog9 said that "the algorithm used for blocking [is] fairly conservative". If a user with many upvoted or accepted answers gets banned after two poor questions, this does not look conservative to me. (Of course, not being a moderator, I have no way of knowing what the deleted questions were.)

Comment: @PostNoBills You can take a look at the non-deleted questions.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I did, without finding anything remotely looking like question-ban material. One duplicate and two reasonable questions.

Comment: @PostNoBills The duplicate is an exact duplicate of one of the reasonable questions.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker But it still seems fairly strict to have a ban due to just one instance of this (unless there are deleted questions with similar problems, which I cannot see).

Answer (score 6):

You should have received a message directing you to the page [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans). According to it, the way to get out of question ban is to edit the posts that got you there. If some of those are now deleted, bring them into shape before undeleting. When the system sees that the negative voting trend on those posts it being reversed, it will unblock you. The process is automatic, and does not involve the moderators of the site.

Comment: You can't edit deleted questions. You can only edit deleted answers.

Comment: The fact that you may need to work magic to turn a bad question good and then somehow attract upvotes to a heavily downvoted one is rather unfortunate.